# My TradingView indicator is Adding Extra Lines on the Daily Charts using the line.new() function

Tags: pine-script, trading, indicator

I'm trying to draw lines on support and resistances as well as a pivot. However, it keeps drawing 2 lines instead of 1. It only does that on the daily charts and above from what I've seen. The code:

```
// NOT ALL CODE IS SHOWN

draw_line(ycoor, style)=>
    line.new(x1 = bar_index, 
             y1 = ycoor, 
             x2 = bar_index - 1, 
             y2 = ycoor, 
             extend = extend.both,
             color = ycoor >= close ? color.new(color.red,10) : color.new(color.lime,10), 
             style = style, 
             width = 1) 
pmh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', high)[1] 
pml = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', low)[1] 
pmc = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'M', close)[1] 
 
pdh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)[1] 
pdl = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)[1] 
pdc = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', close)[1] 

// this is used for user option in the settings for daily of weekly support and resistance 
alt = tl == 'Daily'

pivot = alt ? ((pdh + pdl + pdc) / 3) : (pwh + pwl + pwc) / 3
//there should be more code here for the supports and resistances but I'm not allowed to show. However it is similar.
// the zones variables are used for calculating supports and resistances

multiplier = alt ? 0.001 : 0.002

// formula for first first support and resistance
r3 = alt ? draw_line((zone3 - (pdc * multiplier)), line.style_solid) : draw_line((zone3 - (pwc * multiplier)), line.style_solid)
s3 = alt ? draw_line((zone3 + (pdc * multiplier)), line.style_solid) : draw_line((zone3 + (pwc * multiplier)), line.style_solid)
```

[This is what it looks like on the Daily chart. There are so many additional lines added.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk1sR.png)

[This is what it is supposed to look like. There should only be **3 zones above and below the pivot (yellow line)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8v2o.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you. **Let me know if you need more info.**

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing half of the variables and is not compilable.
To prevent the double print of lines you should delete the previous line with `line.delete` or relocate the position with `line.set_x`(`line.set_xy`, `line.set_x2` etc) functions.

```
var line l1 = na
if condition
    line.delete(l1[1])
    l1 := line.new(x, y, x2, y2 ... )
```